# CodeIgniter - dynamic pages - default controller url

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php

**edit**

my solution in routes.php:

```
$route['news'] = 'news_controller';
$route['gallery'] = 'gallery_controller';
$route['(:any)'] = 'sites/$1';
```

and in my site conroller:

```
function index($site_id = '') {
  //sanitize $site_id.
  $this->site = $this->sites_model->get_site($site_id);
  //etc.
}
```

THX to YAN

**question:**

so i wrote a little CMS with CodeIgniter. The admin can create sites. the site opens automatically when the segment of the url is like one in the DB. eg mysite.com/sites/about will call the "About" site. this works fine.

now i got a problem with my URL. i want this url

http://www.mysite.com/sites/about

turns to this:

http://www.mysite.com/about

the problem is, that i cannot use the routes.php and set wildcards for each site. (because they are dynamic and i dont know wich site the customer will create - and i dont want to edit the routes.php file for each site he will create - this should be done automatically)

the problem is i got other fix controllers too, like news, gallery or contact:
mysite.com/news, mysite.com/gallery, ...they work fine

so here is my Site Controller:

```
class Sites extends Public_Controller {

public $site;
public $url_segment;

public function _remap($method)
{
    $this->url_segment = $this->uri->segment(2);

    $this->load->model('sites_model');
    $this->site = $this->sites_model->get_site($this->url_segment);

    if($this->site !== FALSE)
    {
        $this->show_site($this->site);
    }
    else
    {
        show_404($this->url_segment);
    }
}

public function show_site($data)
{
    $this->template->set('site', FALSE);
    $this->template->set('site_title', $data['name']);
    $this->template->set('content',$data['content']);
    $this->template->load('public/template','sites/sites_view', $data);
}}
```

and this is the Site_model who checks the database...if the url_segment fits the title in the DB:

```
class Sites_model extends CI_Model {

public function get_site($site_url)
{
    if($site_url != ""){
        $this->db->where('name', $site_url);
        $query = $this->db->get('sites', 1);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->row_array();
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
} }
```

i think i need something who checks if the controller exists (the first segment of the url) when not call the Site controller and check if the site is in the DB and when this is false then call 404.

any suggestions how this can be solved?

btw: sry for my english

regards GN

Answer (score 2):

You can handle `routes.php` in the following way, just keep the `(:any)` value last:

```
$route['news'] = 'news_controller';
$route['gallery'] = 'gallery_controller';
$route['(:any)'] = 'sites/$1';
```

In your sites controller route to the specific site using the data from the URL.

```
function index($site_id = '') {
    //sanitize $site_id.
    $this->site = $this->sites_model->get_site($site_id);
    //etc.
}
```

Comment: thx for reply.
yeah this would go but is there any solution with no wildcards in the routes.php? i want to make it dynamically. when i choose this solution and i create a new controller, i have to edit the routes.php and set a wildcard. and at the end there will be a lot controller. (and i dont want to write a wildcard for each of them)

u know what i mean? (btw: sry for my english)

Comment: What new controllers? If you are adding a new section to your site, you will need to update `routes.php` anyway. You won't need to create a new controller for each site.

Comment: no i mean other controlles like "gallery" or "forum". eg the forum files: controllers/forum.php and the url is mysite.com/forum. i dont need to edit the routes.php. at the end there will be more controllers of these. and when i write it like u said then i have to edit the routes.php for each controller i will create in future. this isn't very bad :) but a dynamic solution would be better.

Comment: ok i decided too choose your reply :) but it didnt work. when i call mysite.com/about it shows the 404 error. but when i call mysite.com/sites/about it works. it seems that the remap function dont work. any suggestions, why?

Comment: Please edit your question with the code of your `routes.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I am having trouble understanding the full intent of the question, but, from what I can tell, don't you simply need to add:

```
if ($this->uri->segment(1) != 'sites')
     ... // handle malformed URL
```

Comment: sry my english is bad (from austria)
yeah thats true then he would call the other controllers. but at the end i dont want the segment "sites" anyway. from mysite.com/sites/about to mysite/about

i like to hide the segment "sites"